# Most Similar Records Query Performance

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a mysql database table with 20 million records.  It grows at roughly 25,000 records per day.  Each record has a number of numeric fields.  I have a similarity query that selects the 10 most similar records to a specified record as follows:

```
SELECT 1000 + 
    IF(p2.ph != p.ph,-50,0) +  
    ABS(p2.ss - p.ss)/6.1 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.fxx - p.fxx)/6.4 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.fxz - p.fxz)/5.35 * -50 +  
    ABS(p2.px - p.px)/.94 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.pz - p.pz)/.92 * -50 +  
    ABS(ABS(p2.x0) - ABS(p.x0))/.71 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.z0 - p.z0)/.46 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.sr-p.sr)/669.5 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.sd-p.sd)/68.2 * -50 
    AS sim_score 
FROM tableP p, tableP p2  
WHERE p.pid = 123 
    AND p.uid != p2.uid
    -- AND p2.ss>0 
    -- AND p2.ph = p.ph
    -- AND ABS(p2.ss - p.ss) < 3.5
    -- AND ABS(p2.fxx - p.fxx) < 3.5
    -- AND ABS(p2.fxz - p.fxz)<3
    -- AND ABS(p2.px - p.px)<.6
    -- AND ABS(p2.pz - p.pz)<.6
    -- AND ABS(p2.z0 - p.z0)<.35
    -- AND ABS(ABS(p2.x0) - ABS(p.x0))<.5
    -- AND ABS(p2.sr-p.sr)< 350
ORDER BY 
    1000 + 
    ABS(p2.ss - p.ss)/6.1 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.fxx - p.fxx)/6.4 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.fxz - p.fxz)/5.35 * -50 +  
    ABS(p2.px - p.px)/.94 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.pz - p.pz)/.92 * -50 +  
    ABS(ABS(p2.x0) - ABS(p.x0))/.71 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.z0 - p.z0)/.46 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.sr-p.sr)/669.5 * -50 + 
    ABS(p2.sd-p.sd)/68.2 * -50 DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

The commented lines are a way to limit the comparison to more similar records.  I don't really like that idea, but it does speed this up a bit and serves the purpose of finding the 10 most similar records.

This query takes 5-25 seconds after caching, and will generally take 45+ seconds on first load.  This is obviously inadequate for a web page.  Is the structure of this query sound or is there a better way to do this?

Ideally, I'd like to have another table that stores the similarity scores each day.  Essentially, it would have two pid keys and a score.  That will speed up the prior query, however creating this is would be a mammoth nightly task as I'd be creating roughly 25,000 x 20,000,000 records nightly.

My second question is how can I calculate those bulk similarity score records efficiently?

Comment: Why is it 25,000 x 20,000,000 nightly?  Wouldn't it be 25,000 x 10 rows nightly?

Comment: @hannah-vernon No, I really want to store a similarity score versus every record from other users.  The top 10 serves the purpose of comparing individual records, but I'd use the full comparison to compare users.

Comment: How many _terabytes_ of disk space do you have?  25K * 20M = 500 _billion rows_.  How long does it take to generate that much data?

Comment: If you are comparing each pair, then it is 20M * 20M, that's 400 _trillion_ rows!

Comment: @RickJames Well, it would be half the 400 trillion since you wouldn't store the same pair twice.  Two BigInts and a Float are 20 bytes and I think another 12 bytes for headers/keys. That's somewhere around 6500TB.  Storage is cheap these days...

Comment: But, have you seen a system that can hold that much data?  It might be over $1 million.  How many racks do you have room for?

Comment: Why `BIGINT`, not `INT UNSIGNED`?

Comment: @RickJames Agreed on INT UNSIGNED as the better datatype.  That will cut down the size.  Still elephantine.  Quite possible I should just create a user similarity score and store that since that will be the goal of this exercise.

Comment: Shrinking the numbers saves you half a million dollars.  But think seriously about the other half.  Plus the _weeks_ it will take to compute all the scores.

Comment: What you have is a problem in finding "closeness" in N-dimensional space.  This is a non-trivial mathematical problem.  I have heard of a "cosine" algorithm that somehow helps to "cluster" the items.  You need a mathematician, not a DBA, to reformulate the problem into something manageable.